# Anchor link not going to correct anchor tags

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, anchor

On the website [DanielLmusic.com](http://www.danielLmusic.com), a single page scrolling site, the anchor tags are not being scrolled to correctly and I'm having some difficulty troubleshooting the reason why.Only the bio section is scrolled to correctly. The listen and contact section are off by half a page... I'm using the following smooth scroll code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.internal a').click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); //prevents screen from blinking when link is clicked
    });
  function filterPath(string) {
    return string
      .replace(/^\//,'')
      .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
      .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() { /*<----changed "('a[href" to ('li a[href" to avoid conflict with isotope*/
    if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
       if ($target) {
         var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
         $(this).click(function() {
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000)
           var d = document.createElement("div");
        d.style.height = "101%";
        d.style.overflow = "hidden";
        document.body.appendChild(d);
        window.scrollTo(0,scrollToM);
        setTimeout(function() {
        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
            }, 10);
           return false;
         });
      }
    }
  });
});
/*! Smooth Scroll - v1.4.5 - 2012-07-22
* Copyright (c) 2012 Karl Swedberg; Licensed MIT, GPL */
</script>
```

and I'm using separate anchor ids in the html as following:

```
<div id="pages">
        <a id="bioanchor"></a>
        <div id="biopage">
```

...

```
<div id="listenpage">
            <a id="listenanchor"></a>
            <h1>Listen</h1>
            <div id="soundsystem">
```

...

```
        <div id="contactpage">

            <a id="contactanchor"></a>
```

If anyone could offer a suggestion on why, I would kindly appreciate it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From first look it seems the variable scrollToM is undefined in the line `window.scrollTo(0,scrollToM);`